# Create a printable formletter in a web-based java application

Tags: java, templates, docx

I want to create a form letter in a Java-based Web application. I should like to provide different templates to the user. The user should be able to customize the templates. For example a templates contains a head with a logo and an address.

I've already looked at several libraries / solutions:

1. A File-based solution: OpenOffice-server with Office templates (dot / dotx ) or Appache POI, RTFTemplate , docx4java , iText
2. A Web-based solution: A rich editor which uses templates like tinyMCE. The templates are coded in HTML and CSS.

I think that HTML as structural descriptive language has no capabilities to define a nice printable document.

Questions:

How do you create a form letter in your java-web-app? 
Is it possible to use a HTML-solution to create nice and stable documents? (using customizeable templates)

Comment: I have tried the tools you mentioned, but I wasn't satisfied with the styling when using the HTML approach, and found docx4j and the likes too laborious and time consuming. I finally decided to create a small library to fit my needs, and document generation has finally become fun again. It doesn't use any of the pre-existing tools, and works directly on the xml files. I can provide a copy if drop me a line.

Comment: Ok, that sounds good. I am interested to take a look.